# Find and update double nested referenced document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 models, which are referenced with one another, I want to search for the first document based on a query (this will always exist and return a result), once that returns to search for the second one which is referenced to the first one (which may or may not exist), and push into the 3rd one which is referenced in the 2nd one.

1. User (Parent Model).
2. Location (Child of User)
3. Reports (Child of Location)

I want something similar to the following:

Search **User** (findById), search for **Location** using query (search for locationName) - if it exists update it and also push into **Reports**, else if Location **doesn't exist**, create one and push into **Reports**.

**Parent Model:**

```
const User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    dateOfBirth: Date,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    verified: Boolean,
    locations: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Locations"
      }
    ]
  })
);
```

**Child Model:**

```
const Locations = mongoose.model(
  "Locations",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    address: String,
    adress2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    zip: String
    reports: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Reports"
      }
    ]
  })
);
```

**Child of Child Model:**

```
const Reports = mongoose.model(
  "Reports",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    severity: String,
    note: String,
    date: Date,
  })
);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Date values should be stored as `Date` object, but **never** as string. It's a design flaw.

Comment: Thank you for noting out the model issue, but this is a very minor flaw at that, as having a string can still serve its purpose. Perhaps we don't want the full date object? I don't think personal preferences for what you are doing, matches what we are doing.. But thank you for your response.

Comment: Well, here on SO you can find hundreds or even thousands of questions, where developers run into problems just because they stored date/time values as string. It is not limited to MongoDB, it applies to any database.

Comment: I went ahead and adjusted it to Date, thank you for keeping me aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, by first setting the report values, setting the location values, saving the report, adding the report number to the location value, then searching for a location based on location ID using **fineOneAndUpdate**:

```
Location.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.locationID},
    {
      $push: {
        reports: report
      }
    },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      };

      if (!result) {
        location.save((err, done) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          };
          User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.body.id },
            {
              $push: {
                locations: done
              }
            },
            (err, doc) => {
              if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({ message: err });
                return;
              };

              res.status(200).send({ message: 'Successfully added new location with report.' });
              return;
            })
        })
      }

      if (result) {
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Successfully updated existing location with report.' });
      }
    }
  );
```